# Date search range previous month to current month

Tags: sql-server

I had a working SQL date search...
(DATEADD (dd,-30, getdate()) <= pymnt_pstd_dt)

it gives me data from the past 30 days, but what I actually need is a comparison of the previous month MTD with the current month MTD

I am currently struggling with a good way to write that for SQL

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: show some samples ??

Answer (score 0):

Here are WHERE statements that will get month to date and previous month to date for your field, pymnt_pstd_dt:

```
WHERE pymnt_pstd_dt BETWEEN DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0) AND GETDATE() --Month to date

WHERE pymnt_pstd_dt BETWEEN  DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())-1,0) AND DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()) --Previous month to date
```

Comment: these work independently of each other, so I used as WHERE pymnt_pstd_dt BETWEEN  DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())-1,0) AND GETDATE() --Previous month to date ...which gives me all... but the problem is month to date, so for example tomorrow I need to compare 11-1 thru 11-3 mtd with 12-1 thru 12-3 MTD and that is where I am getting errors

Comment: The statements I posted do what you're asking for.